# Push plugin not found , ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

i am hashik
I had try to build a ionic framework for build android app,
and i was focus on push notification, but i getting error on "push pluging not found"

[image]

Comment: Cordova plugins do not work with `ionic serve`. You need to try using a device/emulator..

Comment: @suraj thank you, so we wont bother about browser error.? if i build its into android app. will be its work well?

Comment: yes..If you are able to test it in a device it is fine..cordova_not_found in browser does not matter

Comment: its working , thanku @suraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Cordova functionality will not work correctly when testing via the browser. Cordova provides a bridge to the mobile device's native functionality which a desktop browser wouldn't understand. So these files aren't included when serving locally

Comment: so, thats means, we wont bother about browser result.? if i build as android app, will be its work well.?

Comment: If ran on the android device it should work so long as the plugin was added